# URL rewriting to a folder if url has one pattern and ignore the rule if url has another pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following directory structure for the project

```
example
  admin/
  cdn/
  client/
  .htaccess
```

When the url is

- `http://192.168.1.121/example/` or
- `http://192.168.1.121/example` or
- `http://192.168.1.121/example/category/productname` or
- `http://192.168.1.121/example/content/12` and so on,

it should rewrite to `client/` folder.

But if url has `http://192.168.1.121/example/cdn`, it should ignore the rule.

Can anybody help me on this. How to write the rule in `.htaccess`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `/example/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/

RewriteRule ^(?!client/|cdn)(.*)$ client/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!client/|cdn)` is negative lookahead to ignore the rule when URI is `/example/cdn` OR `/example/client`

Comment: thanks, all the cases worked but `http://192.168.1.121/example/` and `http://192.168.1.121/example` didn't work

Comment: No updated rule didn't work either. There is no other rules in the htaccess.

Comment: Yes the `.htaccess` is inside `example` directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127793/discussion-between-anubhava-and-watsmyname).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

`RewriteRule ^/example/cdn . [L]` Do nothing if it starts with "/example/cdn" and stop there

`RewriteRule ^/example /client$0 [L]` Prepend "/client" if it starts with "/example"